# eclipse can not debug, but run is ok

Tags: eclipse, debugging

suddenly, my eclipse does not work in debug model. when click debug button, i got these error messages, and debug failed.

FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]

could anyone help, or gives some help.

Answer (score 0):

i have found solution. "unknown host ERROR" in error message is the key.

just because i used switchhost app to change my mac's hosts file. And line of "127.0.0.1 localhost" had been removed.

so, what need to do to solve this problem is adding "127.0.0.1 localhost" to mac's hosts file.

Answer (score -1):

127.0.0.1 localhost

Add the above entry in /etc/hosts file and you should be good.